# Screendump from within Actionscript 3.0 is it possible or?

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmapdata

We have Bitmap and Bitmapdata objects now. And when using the webcam, we can get raw-pixeldata output from it. But, can we get raw-pixeldata from the "stage" or "swf" object somehow?

I would like to use this to make "small thumbnails" of certain parts of Actionscript applications and these could be **complex compositions of dynamic text, bitmap graphics and movieclips at the same time.** So it would be nice to make a "quick snap" and just get the current combined pixels into one bitmap and then be able to "save that for later use".

Is that possible? is it too easy? am I just looking the wrong place in the Adobe Docs?

**We have images, vectors etc at the same time on stage, so I need to grab the "stage" objects bitmapdata???**

Comment: Hope this will leave a new answer that is solving the initial question. (sorry about unmarking the first answer again)

Comment: EDIT: made the important bit **BOLD** as the first answer didnt solve the problem with complex stage objects.

Comment: Solution: the object passed should be of "Stage" class. Not Sprite, not IBitmapDrawable etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `BitmapData` and call its `draw()` [method](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw()) with the corresponding `DisplayObject`

```
var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(sprite.width, sprite.height, true);
bmpData.draw(sprite);
```

If you want to make thumbnails smaller, create a `Matrix` and call its `createBox` method with required scaling parameters and pass it to the `draw` method.

```
var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(thumbW, thumbH, true);
var mat:Matrix = new Matrix();
mat.createBox(thumbW / sprite.width, thumbH / sprite.height);
bmpData.draw(sprite, mat);
```

Comment: nice! thanks! so logical I almost knew that I must have gotten blind :o) Great! going to try it!

Comment: Would you mind trying to help me out once more? I will ofcause mark the answer if correct again. My mistake the first time. Sorry about that.

Comment: What made you unaccept the answer? Did u try `bmpData.draw(stage);`? What happened? Isn't it working?

Comment: No it isn't not when using Stage. Its probarbly me using the wrong object type somehow.

public function SaveSnapshot(oCanvas:IBitmapDrawable):void
{
var snapshot:BitmapData = new BitmapData(oCanvas.width, oCanvas.height, true, 0x00FFFFFF);
var cropbox:Rectangle =  new Rectangle(0, 0,oCanvas.width,oCanvas.height);
snapshot.draw(oCanvas, new Matrix(),null, null, cropbox, false);

...
}

Comment: Oooohh... just tried to use "Stage" as objecttype. I have been using a "generic" type of displayobject, to make this snapshot function work with everything including the Stage object.

Once I replaced it and wrote "oCanvas:Stage" this worked, I hadnt seen that earlier as the backgrund color from the SWF isnt automatically part of the SWF it seems. Its a minor detail and not important. 

So I WILL mark this solved again. Sorry about my misunderstanding and once again! THANKS!!! Hope you will try to help me someother time again ;-)